# T-SQL to monitor SQL worker threads

Tags: sql-server, monitor

Before changing worker threads on SQL Server 2016 to 2019, how can one monitor, take snapshot of, current worker thread use?

```
select max_workers_count 
from sys.dm_os_sys_info
```

returns the total - 640 in my case

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumWorkers 
FROM sys.dm_os_workers
```

only shows 94.

This works

```
SELECT CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) * 100 FROM sys.dm_os_workers) AS real) / i.max_workers_count 
FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info i
```

Is there a better way to monitor worker usage ?

Comment: Define "better". For what purpose are you monitoring? No particular amount of worker threads is obviously good or obviously bad, and even the observation that the maximum has been reached is not immediately actionable.

Comment: Better would be faster, easier. This works but Stack Exchange solutions are often more eloquent. 
Is there anything I'm missing. When things get bad (slow) output is grouped by tread type. Till then, the code inserts the usage for 'normal" or "base line usage" into a table. Later when the boss asks "why did last nights production run slow"  there are numbers to use.